# Regex matching nested beginning and ending tags

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Here are strings that I'd like to extract the contain between the tags `{{if}}` and `{{\if}}`, I mean the first and last one (inner ones will be rechecked by the engine) :

- "before {{if^^p1^p2}} IN1; {{if^ ^p1}} {{iif}} IN3 {{/if}} IN1-1 {{/if}} after"
- "before {{if^ ^p1}} IN1; {{if^ ^p1}} {{if^ ^p1}} IN3 {{/if}} {{/if}} IN1-1 {{/if}} after"
- "before {{if^ ^p1}} IN1; {{if^ ^p1}} {{if^ ^p1}} IN3 {{/if}} {{/if}} IN1-1 {{if^ ^p1}} IN4 {{/if}} {{/if}} after"

The regex is : `\{\{(if)\}\}(((?!\{\{\/?\1\}\})[\s\S])*(\{\{\1\}\}(?2)*\{\{\/\1\}\})*((?!\{\{\/?\1\}\})[\s\S])*)\{\{\/\1\}\}`

**EDIT 3 : I removed the obligation to support TAGs without ending one. I reformatted the question for futur users, to understand some comments below, see first version of the post**

More, I have it to works for all three at the same time giving me three matches, which is not working on the website regex101. Line breaks have to be supported within the match. Though, I could accept that only last two combined gives two matches because I could change the tag of alone `if` for `iif`.

My other solution is not using regular expressions, but I would like to do so if it's possible.

Comment: Click **code generator** link at [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/cT4eQ2/1), and see `$re = "/\\{\\{(if)\\}\\}(((?!\\{\\{\\/?\\1\\}\\})[\\s\\S])*(\\{\\{\\1\\}\\}(?2)*\\{\\{\\/\\1\\}\\})*((?!\\{\\{\\/?\\\\1\\}\\})[\\s\\S])*)\\{\\{\\/\\1\\}\\}/"; ` - however, you overescaped the pattern. I believe you added an extra ``\`` before the last but one `1`. Try with [`$re = '~{{(if)}}(((?!{{/?\1}})[\s\S])*({{\1}}(?2)*{{/\1}})*((?!{{/?\1}})[\s\S])*){{/\1}}~'`](https://www.regex101.com/r/dJ5wZ3/1)

Comment: Oups, did not see that. Now the real problem. Get more than one match for combined strings.

Comment: If you don't care about what's inside (especially whether {{if}}s are paired) then why not simple `strpos` & `strrpos`?

Comment: Well, this would be my solution without regex, but my current templating engine using Regex and `if` can be other stuff. Now it supports {{TAG}} or {{TAG^SPLITTER^PARAMS}} and I would like to support these + {{TAG^SPLITTER^PARAMS}} with its ending one {{/TAG}}

Comment: What is the final expected output?

Comment: Still seems too complicated to me. You could match opening tag with regex and closing with strrpos. It would be faster and everyone will be able to understand the expression (now and when months pass ;)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew it shall give the same results as when they are alone. So, I mean if you take the last two strings, it shall give two matches. Is it clear ?

Comment: Not quite. Let's use regex101: what is wrongly matched [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/nD9tE9/1)?

Comment: The first two matches are OK. The last string (in this post's list), shall give : ` IN1; {{if}} {{if}} IN3 {{/if}} {{/if}} IN1-1 {{if}} IN4 {{/if}} ` as last match.

Comment: Like [`{{(\w+)}}((?>(?:(?!{{/?\1}}).)+|(?R))*){{/\1}}`](https://www.regex101.com/r/qJ3qZ8/2)?

Comment: Wow ! It doesn't match correctly the first one due to the lonely `{{if}}`, but I could live with it by replacing it by `{{iif}}`.

Comment: It does not match the first if because it is not balanced (no corresponding `{{/if}}` is present). I do not know what the expected behavior is in those cases. Shall I post that regex?

Comment: Have a try with something like [`$regex = '~{{if}}((?s:(?!{{).|(?R))*+){{/if}}|{{if}}~';`](https://regex101.com/r/bJ6sC8/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Go ahead! Post it as answer I will accept it.

Comment: @bobblebubble This expression doesn't take correctly the first string even if I change the lonely `if` to `iif`.

Comment: I will add an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
~{{             # Opening tag start
  (\w+)         # (Group 1) Tag name
  \^            # Aux delimiter
  ([^^\{\}]?)   # (Group 2) Specific delimiter
  \^            # Aux delimiter
  ([^\{\}]+)    # (Group 3) Parameters
 }}             # Opening tag end
  (             # (Group 4)
   (?>          
     (?R)       # Repeat the whole pattern
     |          # or match all that is not the opening/closing tag
     [^{]*(?:\{(?!{/?\1[^\{\}]*}})[^{]*)*
   )*           # Zero or more times
  )
 {{/\1}}        # Closing tag
~ix
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tN4eR7/9)

In general, the expression is based on recursion and a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed). The `[^{]*(?:\{(?!{/?\1[^\{\}]*}})[^{]*)*` part is an unrolled `(?s:(?!{{/?\1}}).)*` pattern that matches any character (`.`) that is not the starting point for a `{{TAG}}` or `{{/TAG}}` character sequences.

You do not need a DOTALL modifier for this pattern as there is no `.` in the pattern.

Here is a [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/oANknb):

```
$re = '~{{(\w+)\^([^^\{\}]?)\^([^\{\}]+)}}((?>(?R)|[^{]*(?:\{(?!{/?\1[^\{\}]*}})[^{]*)*)*){{/\1}}~i'; 
$str = "before {{if^^p1^p2}} IN1; {{if^ ^p1}} {{iif}} IN3 {{/if}} IN1-1 {{/if}} after\nbefore {{if^ ^p1}} IN1; {{if^ ^p1}} {{if^ ^p1}} IN3 {{/if}} {{/if}} IN1-1 {{/if}} after\nbefore {{if^ ^p1}} IN1; {{if^ ^p1}} {{if^ ^p1}} IN3 {{/if}} {{/if}} IN1-1 {{if^ ^p1}} IN4 {{/if}} {{/if}} after"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I do not have time now to think of how to unroll this tempered greedy token right now. I will try once I get back from the walk.

Comment: Ehm, I would prefer to unrolled version as it is less consuming. Though, two things I didn't say to simplify the problem : the curly brackets can be replaced by something else, as square brackets, that is why I was escaping those even if I knew it was not an obligation, but it is for square ones. As in the question's comments, "TAGS" are in fact defined this way {{TAG}} OR {{TAG^SPLITTER^PARAMS_SPLIT_WITH_SPLITTER}}. The new version with ending shall support the tag with params. I tried to be able to support both versions : with and without ending tags, but I will execute this regex first...

Comment: ... and then the current one for lonely tags.

Comment: SPLITTER=Anything except the caret (will be this one if none specified), the beginning and ending characters (now "{", "}"). PARAMS_SPLIT_WITH_SPLITTER=Anything except the beginning and ending characters (now "{", "}"). So an example is : `{{IF^ ^P1 P2}} CONTENT {{/IF}}` OR `{{IF^^P1^P2}} CONTENT {{/IF}}`

Comment: Current "regex" is : `$this->pattern = "/" . $this->startingPattern . "([^$splitter\\$startingOneCharMarker\\$endingOneCharMarker]+)(?:\\$splitter?([^$splitter\\$endingOneCharMarker]+)?\\$splitter([^\\$startingOneCharMarker\\$endingOneCharMarker]+))?" . $this->endingPattern . "/";` where startingPattern firstly equals `\{\{` and endingPattern `\}\}`

Comment: I saw this wonderful regex definition : https://regex101.com/r/tN4eR7/1 . It is not related to my issue, but I learned some there. As referencing. So, if we could create the regex this way, would be nice. A draft : `(?(DEFINE) 
(?<tag>(?&marker))
(?<marker>{{(\w+)}})
)(?&tag)`

Comment: But, I am not able to make work your version using DEFINE. https://regex101.com/r/tN4eR7/2

Comment: You can make it work with DEFINE, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB8vS7/1). However, all capture groups are not kept with DEFINE.

Comment: Ah.. that's bad ! I wanted to do so to clarify the regex, but I will forget it. Than, there is a fourth version which doesn't use DEFINE and tries to add the tag format including params, but some problems appears. https://regex101.com/r/tN4eR7/4

Comment: Well, finally, using your new version using DEFINE, I've been able to catch the CONTENT and the first marker, which is needed. However, the first match is not correct and I still not added the params. https://regex101.com/r/bB8vS7/3

Comment: Confirm me if I am right. I saw the DEFINE version is taking more than four times steps than the one without. It probably means more consuming too. Right ? If, so, I did a nice try, but I prefer to continue with the version without.

Comment: Here is - I guess - [fixed version](https://regex101.com/r/tN4eR7/5). DEFINE recurses subpatterns and that is bound to add some overhead to process all of them each time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111675/discussion-between-master-djon-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Did you see my last comment in the chat session ? (Adding a comment here because not sure you saw it)