# PHP PCRE - Regex upgraded now failing (Catastrophic backtracking) + optimization

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I first posted this question :
[Regex matching nested beginning and ending tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164779/regex-matching-nested-beginning-and-ending-tags)

It was answered perfectly by Wiktor Stribiżew. Now, I wanted to upgrade my Regex expression so that my parameters supports a JSON object (or almost, because lonely '{' and '[' aren't supported).

I have two expressions: one for paired tags, one for lonely tags. I first use the paired one, when all replacements done, I execute the lonely one. The modified lonely one works fine on regex101.com (https://www.regex101.com/r/HIEQZk/9), but the paired one tells me "castatrophic backtracking" (https://www.regex101.com/r/HIEQZk/8) even though in PHP in doesn't crash.

So could anyone help me optimize/fix this fairly huge regex.
Even though there seems to be useless escaping, it is because begin/end markers and the splitter can be customized and thus have to be escaped. (The paired one is not as escaped because it is not the one generated by PHP, but the one made by Wiktor Stribiżew with the modifications I did.)

The only part that I think that shall be optimized/fixed is the "parameters" group which I just modified to support JSON objects. (Tests of these can be seen in the earlier versions of the same regex101 url. The ones here are with a real HTML to parse.)

**Lonely expression**

```
~
 \{\{ #Instruction start

   ([^\^\{\}]+) # (Group 1) Instruction name OR variable to reach if nothing else after then
   (?:
     \^
     (?:([^\\^\{\}]*)\^)? #(Group 2) Specific delimiter
     ([^\{\}]*{(?:[^{}\[\]]+|(?3))+}[^\{\}]*|[^\{\}]*\[(?:[^{}\[\]]+|(?3))+\][^\{\}]*|[^\{\}]+) # (Group 3) Parameters
   )?

 \}\} #Instruction end
~xg
```

**Paired expression**

```
~{{             # Opening tag start
  (\w+)         # (Group 1) Tag name
  (?:           # Not captured group for optional parameters
   (?:          # Not captured group for optional delimiter
    \^          # Aux delimiter
    ([^^\{\}]?) # (Group 2) Specific delimiter
   )?
   \^           # Aux delimiter
   ([^\{\}]*{(?:[^{}\[\]]+|(?3))+}[^\{\}]*|[^\{\}]*\[(?:[^{}\[\]]+|(?3))+\][^\{\}]*|[^\{\}]+)   # (Group 3) Parameters
  )?
 }}             # Opening tag end
  (             # (Group 4)
   (?>          
     (?R)       # Repeat the whole pattern
     |          # or match all that is not the opening/closing tag
     [^{]*(?:\{(?!{/?\1[^\{\}]*}})[^{]*)*
   )*           # Zero or more times
  )
 {{/\1}}        # Closing tag
~ix
```

Comment: you don't want to [make the group atomic](https://www.regex101.com/r/HIEQZk/10), do you?

Comment: What do you mean by "group atomic" ? As I see it now, it's working as before (so OK). Deeper "instructions" are parsed after then. What did you change?

Comment: Backtracking can usually be reduced by use of [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) `(?>` and/or [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). If you use negated classes and don't want the regex engine to "go back and try another way" this can usually - in some case drastically - improve performance. I just changed your first `(?:` to `(?>` but dunno if this is your expected match, so was just a guess. I don't want to dig deeper in your regex :p

Comment: @bobblebubble Previous comments was for you too. I just saw your modification. That's it ? I mean, I just put "(?>" instead of "(?:" ?

Comment: Wherever you want to reduce backtracking use `(?>` instead of `(?:` and watch how it affects the stepscounter in regex101.

Comment: Do you think group 3 could be optimized? (The parameters group)

Comment: @bobblebubble Well, post this as an answer and it's accepted. I'm baffled about this! Learning every day!

Comment: Read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) if you want to understand where the problem comes from.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thank you. I already read it, but still worth to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your `(?:` *non-capturing group*s with `(?>` [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) to prevent/reduce backtracking wherever possible. Those are non capturing as well. And/or experiment with [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) while watching the stepscounter/debugger in regex101.

Wherever you don't want the engine to go back and try different other ways.

[This is your updated demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/HIEQZk/10) where I just changed the first `(?:` to `(?>`